# Moved a Wordpress Blog - now it wants to Reinstall

Tags: wordpress

I moved a Wordpress blog from one server to another. I was able to import the database through PHPmyAdmin and the files are all in place but instead of the expected home page I am getting the following at the end of the URL:

> wp-admin/install.php

Edit: my apologies. I imported the wrong database. Need to close out the posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be you need to set the $table_prefix in your wp-config.php file to the correct value.  Look at your database that contains the WordPress tables.  If the posts table is called wp123_posts then your wp-config.php should have this:

```
$table_prefix = 'wp123_';
```

Note: If WordPress sees a new $table_prefix it tries to do an install.

Answer (score 1):

Look for a config file, and make sure that it's pointing to the right database.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, I got that connection working. I initially got a database connection error. Having fixed that I get install link.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your database with phpmyadmin and be sure you got the tables and database imported OK.

Did you follow these instructions?: [Moving WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I made an error in importing the wrong database.

Answer (score 1):

My apologies to everyone. I made an error in uploading the wrong database. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Don't need to apologize. If I didn't read it here I wouldn't notice that I also uploaded the wrong database. :) Every experience counts.